# Register Device Notification not receiving events for multiple partitions

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mfc, usb

I am using register device notification for receiving USB Insertion/removal events so that I can populate the list present on my application. Here is my sample code for Register device Notification shown below:

```
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;
    ZeroMemory( &NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter) );
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(GUID_DEVINTERFACE_LIST)/sizeof(GUID); i++)
    {
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_LIST[i];
        hDevNotify[i] = RegisterDeviceNotification(this->GetSafeHwnd(), &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
        if(!hDevNotify[i]) 
        {
            WCHAR wszNotifyMsg[70];
            wsprintf(wszNotifyMsg, L"%ls%d\n%ls%d", _T("Error in Registering Device Notification GUID Index:"),
                        i, _T("GetLastError:"), GetLastError());
            MessageBox(wszNotifyMsg);
        }
    }
```

The code works fine when I use a simple usb drive, i get a notification and get all the logical disks present and display it. But when I connect a usb drive for multiple partitions, I receive notification when only one of the partition is mounted and i display it on the screen and after 1 sec other partition is mounted on the computer, but i receive no event.

Can u tell me what Iam doing wrong?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe use `GetLogicalDrives` after receiving device change notification?

Comment: What @BarmakShemirani said - when you connect a USB drive with multiple partitions, there's only one device being added, so you'll only get one notification.